# Why recovery showing content as - "xLê7±A§[jp¬1ÜyL8É\6"

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, partition-recovery, file-recovery

Background :

```
While working, Eclipse hanged suddenly. 
I waited ... after a while system crashed with blue screen 
             and was not booting up after hard restart.
```

Before I proceed I would like to mention :

```
       a. My OS was Windows7_SP1_OS(hereafter referred as w7_1)
       b. I had only one drive C: of 981 GB (i.e. 1 TB)
       c. Drive C: was NTFS showing 981 GB with 834 GB used
```

Then What I did sequentially :

```
1. Started a Clean Install of same OS with same Windows7_SP1_OS 
   on top of w7_1 with my bootable CD.

   Realised it will format and terminated within 2 mins.

   Instead then Did an Upgrade Install of same OS(hereafter referred as w7_2) 
   with same Windows7_SP1_OS on top of w7_1 with my bootable CD.

   While doing so, I kept everything just identical to w7_1 and chose: 
         DO NOT to format 
         Kept same no of drives , file format, space..etc etc anything u can imagine

2. Restarted fine with w7_2 and then :
       a. downloaded testdisk 
       b. created bootable USB Flash of Windows7_SP1_OS by WinToUSB 
                        (hereafter referred as w7_Boot) 
       c. planted the testdisk in the USB

3. Restarted fine with w7_Boot
       a. Tried testdisk deepSearch, analysis showed :

                    Disk 81 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63 
                      Partition     |     Start     |       End         |     Size in sectors
                      ----------        ---------         -------             ---------------    
                    *D HPFS - NTFS  | 0   32   33   | 12     223  19    | 204800     [System Reserved] 
                     M HPFS - NTFS  | 12  223  20   | 121601 25   24    | 1953314816 [ The M drive is w7_2, which I installed as topUp and I dont need it - u can ignore it ] 
                     E HPFS - NTFS  | 147 191  45   | 121601 57   56    | 1951150080 [ this is C drive of my crashed w7_1 HDD ]

                Structure: Ok.                  
                NTFS found using backup sector, blocksize=4096, 998 GB / 938 GiB


4. While using TestDisk, I try to List Files on E, it shows not recoverable. 
   My MBR was OK. So did following -
  i.  Repaired by Creating new MFT [both MFT & backUp MFT are messed up]
  ii. Fixed BS by Rebuild-BS(Boot Sector ) [ backUp BS was not OK ]
  iii. Re write Partition information by deleting partition M and saved Partition info
```

1. Now Rebooted with w7_Boot.
2. My Explorer now shows, following Hard Disk Drives:

   ```
                  a. Local Disk(D:)      
                  a. Local Disk(E:)
   ```

   3. Tried some file recovery scan using Software : 'Acronis @ File Recovery'. And got to see many files:

[image]

**Question:**

a. Why the file content is like that ?

b. How to fix this ?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess, the files are encrypted, or they are simply corrupt.  If you had come to us, before you reinstalled Windows on the same partition, there might have been options you could have tried.  However, you decided to overwrite files, before you attempted to recover the files in question.  It's very likely the files have been partially overwritten, if that is the case, you have no more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the file content is like that?

If I were to hazard a guess, the files are encrypted, or they are simply corrupt. If you had come to us, before you reinstalled Windows on the same partition, there might have been options you could have tried. However, you decided to overwrite files, before you attempted to recover the files in question. **It's very likely the files have been partially overwritten, if that is the case, you have no more options**

> How to fix this?

If the files are corrupt and not encrypted there isn't a solution.  File recovery in a case like this is not guaranteed.  **The fact you were able to recover some files and not other files is an indication you overwrote the data when you reinstalled Windows.**

If the files were encrypted, file recovery would not be possible, but based on the fact you were able to successfully recover some files all indications point towards the fact they are simply corrupt.

> If I want to keep an image of the disk (for future to investigate) then what format of images I create so that can be read by any of Acronis/EaseUS/Active Recovery/Recuva?

There is not a universal format that those programs all support.  You should select a single program, and use it weekly or daily, in order to keep proper backups.  However, you need to backup your backup images also, otherwise the storage devices they are stored on could also fail.

> Now I am scared..I didnt let the windows installation happen by formatting or overwrite....my windows is installed and running from a USB Live CD..still I am getting what you tried to mean...is there any possibility to restore the MFT..I think that has caused the problem

When you selected the same partition, the installation environment, overwrote the data on the partition you selected.  While you didn't delete the partitions, you still overwrote the data, making file recovery in your case not possible.

> Should I try dynamic disk as a single drive and keep image of that to try recovery in future?

Using a dynamic disk would mean if either disk failed, all your data would be lost, making file recovery nearly impossible.

> I have a full Acronis .tib backup of my w7_1 without the new files. Can that help to recover MFT or Boot or anything ?

File recovery in the case you describe is not possible.  Restoring the Acronis True Image backup of your HDD, would only overwrite additional files, making even partial file recovery impossible.  Restoring the MFT in a case like this is only part of the problem, that doesn't appear to be the problem, since you were able to recover some files but not others.

> Just not being expert i have a hunch fixing the Partition and MBR and MFT from that .tib might bring back to me the w7_1 as a logical drive..and i can view the files again ?

While you can mount the image of your HDD, it does not contain the files you want to restore,so viewing the contents of the backup does not solve your problem.

> Any tips please?

**Accept the fact data recovery is not possible in this case.  Learn from the mistakes you made, take more frequent backups, so your next drive failure isn't a big deal.**

Comment: Your question doesn't mention you were attempting to recover images, your only example, was suppose to be a text document but appeared to be corrupt.  Of course it does not really change the outcome, running file recovery software on the partition, will either find the complete files or they won't.  It appears you have done what you can, healthy drives, do not fail in the way you describe.  I would immediately replace the drive with a new one.

Comment: @ArnabDutta - You might have stop the clean install but you still reinstalled Windows over itself.  As I said in my initial comment, had you come to us before you did that, what could be done would be entirely different. File recovery software (at least that we consumers have access to) all work basically the same. A file recovery service might have more luck due to socialized tools that are not typically sold to end consumers.  However, based on the information you have provided, the files are corrupt or incomplete (partially overwritten).

Comment: @ArnabDutta - Your comments are extremely difficult to read.  It's not clear what you are attempting to explain at this point.  I have simply been flagging the comments for a moderator to review.

Comment: @ArnabDutta - While you are welcome to update your question.  However, I won't be updating my answer, since I don't believe file recovery is possible based on the information you have described.

Comment: thats Ok @Ramhound. I wont expect you to bring me to a successful recovery ☺️  I have just few doubt while trying wuld not solve it i know from an expert like you. Still try to comment once a while if you can. No need to change your answer boss.

Answer (score 1):

You have corrupted files, here. Try some another software for data recovery (UFS explorer or R-studio), and make a full scan of partition. 
Than compare the results, maybe some of these software will connect corrupted files better.
Do not install any software or save anything on partition what You want to read.

Comment: Is there any software which recognize the file  by either its start or end structure and tries to repair by putting its header or footer signature ? What I mean is that : If say I had 3 files with memory     0....F1[20...60]...F2[64...80]..F3[90.. 92]...100  and after corruption it became                        0..(corrupt19To23)..60]...F2[64...80]...F3[90.. 92]...100  such that the tool can recognise F1-end pattern at 60 and either suggest or fix-header or ignore F1 but considers F2 F3 ?   Why I'm asking is bcoz i have a feeling so many files cant be corrupted by window repair Upgrade Install

Comment: The software I recommend in answer, try to find as much as possible files (with recognition patterns) and try to complete all files where they found all fragments of files. 
You can also try to do something similar with WinHEX (or some another hex editor, but WinHEX has the best options), but it is manualy procedure.

Comment: please guide me to some Hex Editing details manual...i dont have those softwares